# How to test conditional creation of a Bean with Spring Boot?

Tags: spring-boot, testing, applicationcontext

In module A I have this class hierarchy:

```
public interface Sanitizer<C extends DocumentContext> {
    CommonWorkflowResult<C> sanitizeForInbound(C documentContext);
    CommonWorkflowResult<C> sanitizeForOutbound(C documentContext);
}
```

An abstract base class implements this interface:

```
public abstract class BaseSanitizer<C extends DocumentContext> implements Sanitizer<C> { ... }
```

The first subclass extending the base class:

```
@Component
public class SaxXmlSanitizer<C extends DocumentContext> extends BaseSanitizer<C> { ... }
```

The second class extending the base class:

```
@Component
public class RegExXmlSanitizer<C extends DocumentContext> extends BaseSanitizer<C> { ... }
```

In an different module B I import the dependency (module A) containing the classes above and here I have a configuration defining the beans conditionally on a property being set via application.properties:

```
@Bean
@ConditionalOnProperty(name = "sanitizer.type", havingValue = "REGEX", matchIfMissing = true)
public Sanitizer regExSanitizer() {
    return new RegExXmlSanitizer();
}

@Bean
@ConditionalOnProperty(name = "sanitizer.type", havingValue = "SAX", matchIfMissing = false)
public Sanitizer xmlSanitizer() {
    return new SaxXmlSanitizer();
}
```

How can I write a Spring Boot test to see that a RegExXmlSanitizer Bean exists in the application context if the property sanitizerType=REGEX is set (and the SaxXmlSanitizer Bean does not exist) and vice versa if the property sanitizerType=SAX is set?

I tried:

```
@Test
void testSanitizerExists() {
    this.contextRunner//.withPropertyValues("sanitizerType=SAX")
            .run(context -> Assertions.assertNotNull(context.getBean(SaxXmlSanitizer.class)));
}
```

but I always get a

> NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type
> 'SaxXmlSanitizer' available: expected at least 1 bean
> which qualifies as autowire candidate.

Comment: tried: `getBean(Sanitizer.class)`? (Alternatively you could change the bean declaration, but i think this is not desired)

Comment: ..on this you could assert its class/cast etc.

Comment: I did this already. Take a look at Test code snippet. :-)

Comment: yes..in the test code snippet it is `SaxXmlSanitizer` ..somewhat "more special" than `Sanitizer`, isn't it!?

Comment: and `"sanitizer.type"` versus `"sanitizerType=SAX"` is strange, but could work due to "relaxed binding" ;)

Comment: You're right. I didn't recognize Sanitizer.class/SaxXmlSanitizer.class. I changed it in the test but it ends with the same exception.

Comment: I corrected sanitizer.type in the meanttime to be sanitizerType in both application.properties and Bean declaration.

Comment: then it must be "in the `contextRunner`", please post a [mre].

Answer (score 0):

I got it running doing it this way:

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = {RegExXmlSanitizer.class}, properties = {"sanitizerType=REGEX"})
@ActiveProfiles("test")
class RegExXmlSanitizerTest {

    @Autowired
    private RegExXmlSanitizer<DocumentContext> sanitizer;

    private final ApplicationContextRunner contextRunner = new ApplicationContextRunner()
            .withPropertyValues("sanitizerType=REGEX")
            .withConfiguration(AutoConfigurations.of(SanitizerTestConfig.class));

    @TestConfiguration
    static class SanitizerTestConfig {
        @Bean
        @ConditionalOnProperty(name = "sanitizerType", havingValue = "REGEX", matchIfMissing = true)
        public Sanitizer regExXmlSanitizer() {
            return new RegExXmlSanitizer();
        }
    }

    @Test
    void testSanitizerExists() {
        this.contextRunner.withPropertyValues("sanitizerType=SAX")
                .run(context -> Assertions.assertNotNull(context.getBean(RegExXmlSanitizer.class)));
    }
...
}
```